# from ... import ... with packages

Tags: packages

In Python we can import packages using

`import packagename`

or, if we only need a specific function, we can write

`from packagename import functionname`

Can something similar be done in LaTeX?

This would solve the common problem where a command is needed, the corresponding package is included, but later it turns out the command is not needed after all, but one forgets which package to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is impossible, and that's due to the fact that TeX is nothing like a procedural language. In Python, you have classes and functions, and you can clearly see what depends on what. In TeX, you can't see this at all, the package is typically one very complicated and self-intertwined monster.