# Asserting that package contains command

Tags: packages

I would like to do something like this:

`\usepackage{mypackage}
\assertpackagecontains{mypackage}{mycommand}`

Here, if the `mypackage` package does not contain the `\mycommand` command, then an error is produced.

By including a line like this for each esoteric command used, we could enforce some discipline as to which packages are loaded for which purpose.

Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307737/from-import-with-packages applies here as well?

Comment: Macros are not bound to `packages` in this sense. You can check whether a macro is defined, but not directly which package provides this macro (as far as I know) -- and in fact, many packages redefine existing macros.

Comment: OK, so `\usepackage` is basically like `\input` I guess

Comment: You can use `\providecommand{\mycommand}{}` to be on the safe side that the macro exists, but this does not guarantee that the code compiles (or does what you intend it should do)

Comment: Yes, after option processing, it comes down to `\InputIfFileExists`

Comment: Surely the answer to the question actually asked is simple: `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\assert[2]{\texttt{#1} indeed contains \texttt{\textbackslash #2}!}
\begin{document}
\assert{parskip}{QuietHampering}
\end{document}`. Perhaps you meant to ask something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps not what is requested!

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\assertpackageprovidescommand}[2]{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{#2}{}{%
    \usepackage{#2}%
  }
  \@ifundefined{#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error!}{Package #2 does not provide \string#1}{See blabla}{}
  }
}
\@onlypreamble\assertpackageprovidescommand
\makeatother

\assertpackageprovidescommand{includegraphics}{graphicx}
\assertpackageprovidescommand{rotatebox}{graphicx}
\assertpackageprovidescommand{foofoo}{graphicx} % Must fail

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well it would be preferable if `\assertpackageprovidescommand` already existed instead of having to code it ourselves. Thanks though.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen: No, not this way. You've to incorporate into the LaTeX format then, such that is loaded automatically when `(pdf)latex` etc. is run. But in total, the usefulness is limited, in my point of view